# Replacement for deprecated OpenGL: glEnum GL_LIGHTING

Tags: opengl, graphics, lighting

The books and websites I've gone through all tell me to use glEnable(GL_LIGHTING) to enable lighting.  I've seen that this enum is now deprecated.  What has superseded it and what other deprecated items should I look out for in lighting?  Even new SO questions still mention GL_LIGHTING, so I haven't had much luck finding how to change this.

Comment: "*The books and websites I've gone through all tell me to use glEnable(GL_LIGHTING) to enable lighting.*" Did you look at the [ones on this list](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides), none of which suggest that you use any fixed-functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's replaced by custom shaders. You're supposed to create any lighting-based variables that you need and treat them just like any other uniform in your shaders.

There's not a 'built-in' replacement for fixed pipeline lighting, you're expected to implement it yourself.